# Se sabe de algún lugar/foro donde poder alquilar o ofrecer servicios de programación?

Tags: discusión

No sé bien bien si esta pregunta la puedo hacer aquí o no, pero allá vamos...

Ahora mismo este foro por lo que tengo entendido es de los más grandes si no el que más(en el caso de SO inglesa), pero me gustaría saber si puedo anunciar o alquilar servicios de programación, en mi caso estoy buscando personal para cierto tipo de programación, pero me interesaría también saber algún lugar donde yo anunciarme por si acaso fuera la situación.

La cosa es que sé que hay lugares, pero no se cuales exactamente, pensé que en un foro de programación como este alguien lo sabría

Y... si fuera el caso, estaría bien implementar un apartado para anunciarte o buscar anunciantes en esta misma web???

Comment: Entiendo que la red inglesa ofrece algunos servicios de búsqueda de talento (https://stackoverflow.co/talent/) y de publicidad, (https://stackoverflow.co/advertising/)  pero lamentablemente creo que en SOes no hay nada de esto

Comment: Dada tu reputación podrías darte una vuelta por la sala de chat y preguntar o  también muchos usuarios tienen información de contacto.

Comment: Si querés, podés agregar a la descripción de tu perfil algun mensajito.

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a poner anuncios en SOes, lo básico es que te pongas en contacto con la gente de ventas de espacio publicitario. Puedes promoverte en tu perfil de usuario, por ejemplo, poner el URL de tu sitio web y poner en tu biografia los servicios que ofreces. Si tienes un blog o publicaciones que sirvan de soporte a una respuesta puedes poner enlaces a estos siempre y cuendo esten relacionados con lo que se está preguntando. En los comentarios podrías sugerir que te contacten por otro medio pero sólo si la conversación lleva a ello de forma orgánica, de lo contrario muy seguramente el comentario será reportado como spam y si esto lleva a un bloqueo difícilmente una apelación procederá.

Te dejo el enlace al artículo de ayuda sobre el tema

- [No te conviertas en spammer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Si sabes inglés vale la pena que visites Meta Stack Overflow y Meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com)